# How can I match this pattern (characters a-z, numbers ) between two brackets?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this code , and I would like to match this pattern:

- All characters a-z , A-Z between two "" .
- The variables should be between square brackets.

How can I achieve that?

This input should be accepted :

```
["a1","a2"]
```

This is my code and what I've tried:

```
 string text = "["a1","a2"]";
 Regex rg2 = new Regex(@"[^\""a-z|A-Z|0-9\""$]+(, [^\""a-z |A-Z |0-9\""$]+)+");
 if (rg2.IsMatch(text)
      Console.WriteLine("True");
```

Comment: Maybe `Regex rg2 = new Regex(@"^\[""[a-zA-Z0-9]+""(?:,\s*""[a-zA-Z0-9]+"")*]$");`? See https://ideone.com/t9VHon

Comment: That looks exactly like a JSON array. As such, isn't the best way forward to use a JSON deserializer?

Comment: No , I wouldn't like to use JSON array .

Comment: Great, then I posted the answer. Note the `"` in a verbatim string literal should be defined with a double `"`: `@"abc""def"` is a `abc"def` text, there is no need to escape it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```cs
Regex rg2 = new Regex(@"^\[""[a-zA-Z0-9]+""(?:,\s*""[a-zA-Z0-9]+"")*]$");
Regex rg2 = new Regex(@"\A\[""[a-zA-Z0-9]+""(?:,\s*""[a-zA-Z0-9]+"")*]\z");
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/tLtmNy):

```cs
string text = "[\"a1\",\"a2\"]";
Regex rg2 = new Regex(@"\A\[""[a-zA-Z0-9]+""(?:,\s*""[a-zA-Z0-9]+"")*]\z");
Console.WriteLine(rg2.IsMatch(text)); // => True
```

*Details*:

- `\A` - start of string
- `\["` - a `["` fixed string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - one or more ASCII letters/digits
- `"` -  a double quotation mark
- `(?:,\s*"[a-zA-Z0-9]+")*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `"[a-zA-Z0-9]+"` - `"`, one or more ASCII alphanumeric chars, `"`
- `]` - a `]` char
- `\z` - the very end of string.